# How to increase and decrease quote levels in Thunderbird?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird, text-formatting

Is there a way to change the quote level in Thunderbird without any special add-ons?

Ideally, I'd like a shortcut to change quote leves from

> > > this

to

> > this

and the other way around easily.

I cannot find it on-line and it seems there is no such option in the Thunderbird menu (only *Increase / Decrease Indent* which is not the same).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's pretty clumsy but I can do it with sequences of cutting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>) or copying (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) text from anywhere and using this command to paste it in Thunderbird as a quote block (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>).

You need to have the cursor at quote level *n* when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to get the pasted text at quote level *n+1*.

Comment: This is ridiculous. I love it.

Comment: Could you add a note that the user is supposed to cut the text and paste it with Ctrl-Shift-o, which pastes with just one quote level higher than it was cut into a clipboard? It wasn't obvious to me at first.

Comment: It doesn't quite work that way.  The quote level produced by Ctrl-Shift-o is one level deeper than the level _where the cursor is_.  It is not affected at all by the quote level the text was at when it was cut to clipboard using Ctrl-x.  So I think the answer is more accurate as it stands...

Comment: I might have described it poorly. The point is that I it is not obvious at first that *applications of Ctrl-x* is in fact just cutting. I guess that the current description + our comments is enough for anyone to figure it out. :)